# Spring-Content 1.2.7: Identifier for the ContentStore

Tags: spring-content-community-project

**What I intend to do**: I'd like to use multiple `ContentStore`s in the same system: one for freshly uploaded files (filesystem), one for (long term) archiving (AWS S3 or maybe GCS).

**What I tried** (and what actually does work):

1. Extended class `File` by another attribute `private String contentStoreName;`
2. Creating two `ContentStore`s like described here: [Spring-Content: Moving files from content store to another content store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032540/spring-content-moving-files-from-content-store-to-another-content-store)
3. Extending `gettingstarted.FileContentController.setContent(Long, MultipartFile)` by setting an identifier for the used `ContentStore`: `f.get().setContentStoreName("regular");`
4. Getting the content in dependence of the stored `contentStoreName`:

   ```
   InputStream input;
   if (Objects.equals(f.get().getContentStoreName(), "archive")) {
       input = archiveContentStore.getContent(f.get());
   } else {
       input = regularContentStore.getContent(f.get());
   }
   ```
5. Changing the `contentStoreName` when moving from one `ContentStore` to another:

   ```
   Resource resource = regularContentStore.getResource(fileEntity.get());
   archiveContentStore.setContent(fileEntity.get(), resource);
   fileEntity.get().setContentStoreName("archive");
   filesRepo.save(fileEntity.get());
   ```

**The smell about this**: Despite this code works, I guess it's not the intended way, because `Spring-content` usually does a lot with annotations and some magic in the background. But I can't find an annotation for an identifier / name for the `ContentStore`.

**Question**: Is there a more intended way of doing this in `Spring-Content`?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond supporting multiple storage modules in a single application (via the FilesystemContentStore, et al annotations) Spring Content does not currently provide any logic for supporting classes of storage.  That would be a layer that you need to create on top of Spring Content as you are starting to do.

In terms of Spring Content annotations it might be helpful for you to understand what modules manage what annotations.

Spring Content storage modules; FS, S3, etc all implement `ContentStore` and in doing so all provide management of the `@ContentId` and `@ContentLength` attributes (in addition to managing the actual content operations).  Looks like you are using the `ContentStore` API (`getContent`/`setContent`) and therefore your entity's content id and length attributes will be managed for you.

Spring Content REST then provides management of `@MimeType` and `@OriginalFileName` attributes (in addition to providing comprehensive REST endpoints).  My guess is that you are not using this and instead providing your own custom controller REST API that uses the 'contentStoreName' attribute to decide which store to put/get the content from.  This approach seems fine.

That is all to say that a slightly more elegant approach, perhaps, that would allow you to use Spring Content REST *might* be to implement your own custom `Archiving` Storage module and encapsulate the "switching" logic you have above in its `setContent`/`getContent`/`unsetContent` methods.  Note, this is actually quite easy (just 4 or 5 classes and I would point you at the GCP and Azure modules for inspiration).  Note, that the REST API (for ContentStore) only calls those 3 APIs too so those are the only ones you would need to implement.  This would mean you get to use Spring Content REST and all the features it provides; set of rest endpoints, byte range support and so on as well as encapsulating your "archiving" logic nicely.